How to add a list of variations with links to the product card (loop grid in elementor pro)?
How to display the available product variations by the size attribute on the product card ("loop grid" in elementor)?
Here below, an example of how it should look:

Tried to create a shortcode that could be inserted into the cart (by adding the following to my theme's functions.php file):
function display_product_sizes() {
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product || ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $sizes = array();

    foreach ( $available_variations as $variation ) {
        $size = $variation['attributes']['size'];
        if ( ! in_array( $size, $sizes ) ) {
            $sizes[] = $size;
        }
    }

    if ( empty( $sizes ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    return implode( ', ', $sizes );
}

add_shortcode( 'product_sizes', 'display_product_sizes' );

